# VBScipt to Excel - Range Function Syntax

Tags: excel, vbscript, range

re: Excel 2007

I'm using VBScript to create an Excel file and have a small issue with Syntax i think...

If i do this it happily pastes my chart from my application to a sheet in Excel at cell A1:-

```
ActiveDocument.GetSheetObject("CH_Contacts").CopyTableToClipboard True
XLSheet2.Paste XLSheet2.Range("A1")
```

What i now need to do is substitute variables instead of A1 but i'm unsure of the correct syntax to do this.

I have 2 variables called num_cols & num_rows so i want to do something like...

```
XLSheet2.Paste XLSheet2.Range(num_cols,num_rows)
```

I notice if i record an Excel macro and drag an area it produces this sort of thing...

```
Range("PV58:PZ58").Select
```

So do i need quotes somewhere as well ? Do i need the colon in there too with variables?

Any help appreciated

Comment: What are the values of` `num_cols` and `num_rows`? And from those values, what is the *expected* range object that should result?

Comment: While you can do this with `Range`, I find it more straight-forward to use `Cells` in these cases. With `Cells`, you reverse the values and supply the row first and the column second and you can easily use variables, like this: `Cells(r, c)`

Comment: I have a suspicion that this: `Range(num_cols,num_rows)` needs to be this: `Range(num_cols & "," &  num_rows)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `num_cols` and `num_rows` are Long/Integer data type representing the column/row *number* (i.e., Column A == 1, Row 16 == 16, etc.), then use the `Cells` property:

```
XLSheet2.Paste XLSheet2.Cells(num_rows, num_cols)
```

The `Cells` property returns the range at the specified index of row number/column number, so:

```
Cells(1,1)  '## Range("A1") -- Row 1, Column 1

Cells(13, 5) '## Range("E13") -- Row 13, column 5
```

Etc.

> So do i need quotes somewhere as well ? Do i need the colon in there too with variables?

No, only if you are trying to build a literal address string, like "A6:A13", and even then it's not strictly necessary and the range can usually be constructed with another method like `Resize` or `Offset`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - sounds promising - i've been side tracked on to another job but will post back when i've had a chance to test it

Comment: Works nicely thanks - as pointed out earlier num_rows should be first ie XLSheet2.Paste XLSheet2.Cells(num_rows,num_cols)